# How do I use regression to model 3 IVs and 1 DV?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, modeling

I'm trying to study electromagnetic braking. 
I have 3 Independent Variables (different factors affecting the force exerted on a conductor moving through a magnetic field) and the dependent variable (the force).

I am way out of my depth when it comes to multivariate regressions and although I have some basic knowledge about ML I really don't know what to do, any help - even just a hint at the right direction - would be really helpful.

Additionally, this may seem moot but how much data would I need to create a model of the form: Force = Some combination of the 3 IVs;? As I think this might depend on which method I use, what are the different ways I can create this model?

Also, I don't have to use any particular language/tool so that shouldn't be an issue.

Cheers!

Comment: You can scatterplot each IV vs. force to check for any obvious data collection errors and visually determine if any obvious relationship (linear, exponential, etc.) shows up. A minimum linear model would be "force = constant + (a * IV1) + (b * IV2) + (c * IV3)". I would start there and analyze the results to improve the model, as this is the bare minimum.

Comment: Right, that makes sense! I'm trying to read some more literature on this topic and I seem to have wrapped my head around theory; forgive me if this seems obvious but I'm still trying to visualize all these dimensions. Now I'm stuck on implementing this. Let's assume that my data has been checked and is clean, how would I go about creating that linear model (also assuming the relation is linear for the time being)? I was thinking about trying to modify normal linear regression paired with gradient descent. Do you think that would work or is there a 'better' way to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question in your comments, here is a Python example that will perform multiple regression and plot the errors. This uses non-linear regression so you can experiment with non-linear equations.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

IV1 = (-1.0, -2.2, -3.3, -4.4, -5.5, -6.7)
IV2 = (21.0, 22.2, 23.3, 24.4, 25.5, 26.7)
IV3 = (51.0, 52.2, 53.3, 54.4, 55.5, 56.7)
all_IV = numpy.array([IV1, IV2, IV3])

ForceData = (11.1, 12.1, 13.1, 14.1, 15.1, 16.1)


# function to be fitted
def modelFunction(data, a, b, c, offset):
    f = (data[0] * a) + (data[1] * b) + (data[2] * c) + offset
    return f


# some initial parameter values
# these might be estimated from scatterplots
initialParameters = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

# perform the fit
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(modelFunction, all_IV, ForceData, initialParameters)

# We can at least plot the errors
errors = modelFunction(all_IV, *fittedParameters) - ForceData

plt.plot(ForceData, errors, 'D') # plot the raw data as a scatterplot
plt.show()

print('a, b, c, offset:', fittedParameters)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will be testing this out as soon as I finish collecting my data! I just have a quick question, while creating the variables at the beginning, I assume (for the modelFunction) it is in the form: ForceData[0] = (IV1[0] * a) + (IV2[0] * b) + (IV3[0] * c) + offset? So essentially, I'm just trying to figure out how to put my data into variables in the correct order. Again thank you so much! This was really helpful!

Comment: Using the "all_IV" allows Python to use a single reference for all data. Using IV1]0[, IV2[0], and IV3[0] in your recent comment does not allow a single reference to all of the data. Put your data into the variables as shown in the example and you should be fine. I suggest starting with a small subset of the data to make sure it works OK, and then try using all of the data once that seems to work. There are various ways to read the data from text files instead of combining the data and fitting code, here the data and code was combined to keep the example simple and just illustrate the fitting.